# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null) When trying to use googleSignIn in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-api, google-signin

I have read all the Stackoverflow questions and github issues I can find but nothing worked.

I am trying to sign in and authenticate Calender scopes using GoogleSignIn.

I have -

- used the gradle task in Android Studio to get my SHA-1 and SHA256 fingerprints.
- added the SHA-1 to my OAuth2 credentials in Google cloud console.
- added BOTH SHA-1 and SHA256 keys to my firebase console
- replaced the google-services.json file after doing so.
- added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` to my project's build.gradle file,
  and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`  inside my app's build.gradle file.
- ran `flutter clean` after all of this.

I checked it both in debug and release mode, both on a phone and an emulator.

does anyone have any idea what am I missing?

This is my code:

this is in initState():

```
    _signIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((user) async {
      if(user != null) {
        d.log('${user.id}, ${user.email}, ${user.photoUrl}');
        final authUser = (await _signIn.authenticatedClient());
        if(authUser == null) {
          d.log('no user');
        } else {
          _calendar = CalendarApi(authUser);
        }
      }
    });
```

and this is when I press the login button:

```
  void _onPress() {
    if(_calendar == null) {
      _signIn.signIn();
    } else {
      ...
      });
    }
  }
```

This is my `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at D:\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (11 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Itay Rabin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is the error I get:

```
E/flutter ( 4782): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter ( 4782): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 4782): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter ( 4782): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4782): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
E/flutter ( 4782): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4782): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:248:30)
E/flutter ( 4782): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4782): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:378:5)
E/flutter ( 4782): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4782):
```

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: are you running on debug or release?

Comment: you need to add a  signingConfig signingConfigs.release(or debug ) in app/build.gradle file.

Comment: I added the error message. @RohitChaurasiya I added it to the gradle file, didn't help. I tried both debug and release.

Answer (score 13):

I also want to add additional useful info:

If you have a problem with **Google sign in** for an app downloaded from **Google Play Console**:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, z1.b: 10: , null, null)

You need to add SHA-1 from Google Play console to Firebase

[image]

Comment: You are my life-saver. I ran into "PlatformException(sign_in_failed, m4.b: 10: , null, null)" and panicked like crazy. It's working after adding the fingerprints like you suggested!

Comment: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, m4.b: 10: , null, null) <-- this issue has been solved by this solution.

Answer (score 2):

So, after 2 days of trying I found and followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5WgU6ERZzA&t=0s) and got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Error code 10 means the SHA key is wrong . So once you create SHA key using this command "`./gradlew signingReport`" . Many SHA keys swill generate . Select the SHA key corresponding to your jks file and put inside firebase console under android app section, this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5WgU6ERZzA) helped me .

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't add serverClientId or clientId to the GoogleSignin Object. Just an empty object. I don't know why but it went well.

Hope helps someone.