# Flutter android can not sign with google_sign_in

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have same problem with
[PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null) When trying to use googleSignIn in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462188/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception)
I will tried but didn't work
In IOS, it work and have info user but serverAuthCode is null

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.4 at /Users/cuongtruongquoc/Documents/fvm/3.0.4
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 85684f9300 (2 days ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
    • Dart version 2.17.5
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/cuongtruongquoc/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • Live (mobile)              • AHB00036590   • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • sdk gphone x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos         • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.53

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Comment: Have you activated Google login authentication?

Comment: how to active GG login authentication? I read document but i don't know about it

Comment: 1) Open your project in firebase console. 2) Find the authentication menu option. 3) Go to sign in methods. 4) Select google and enable it

Answer (score 1):

Go to Play store and Search for "App Integrity"

Google play store app integrity

[image]

Then
Copy the SHA Keys and Add into the Firebase or Google Cloud signing keys.

and then you are good to go.

worked for me.

Comment: It did not work with me, it works when I use native code